# Pulling Info from one tab to another in Google Sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

My spreadsheet contains several tabs. Each tab contains the same headers. My co-workers fill in their tab, so several tabs contain a lot if information. I own the Master tab.

Is there a formula to pull info from the 13 other tabs into the Master tab? Am I able to sort it once it's pulled over?

[image: Sample Reg-Systems tab]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use

```
tab_name!cell_address
```

e.x

```
Reg_Systems!C13
```

Or to get certain data from some user you could use

```
=VLOOKUP()
```

Its a command from Excel. Its kinda difficult to merge multiple tables from multiple sheets into one file.

You could however ask your users to export their tables and then you can combine the tables and put them into one table.

Comment: Don't forget the = Sign to complete the equation, at least in Google Sheets :D ;) `=Reg_Systems!C13`

Comment: Once all the tabs pull into the master cell, will all my formulas also be copied and will I be able to sort by date or any other column I would need to sort?

Comment: So if I have multiple tabs would I just write:                          =Reg_Systems!C13                                                                    =Housing!C13

Comment: @maymartin You are only getting the cell value from the sheet!cell_name. The formula which calculates the cell value will still be there not the actual formula.

Comment: When I type in =Reg_Systems!A12:I200 I get an error message that says An array value could not be found. Can I only copy a row or column, but not the entire sheet?

Comment: @maymartin Why would you want to copy the whole sheet? Could you show us what you mean by this? Show us the other tabs aswell. btw try click and dragging your formula

Comment: I added a pic of a portion of the Reg_Systems tab. I am responsible for getting the Master tab updated with data from the other tabs. I'm currently copying and pasting the data from each tab into the Master tab. My co-workers are responsible for adding their data into the other tabs. Some contain very little data and other tabs can contain a lot of data. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I know get what you mean @maymartin I'll try to find a better solution to this.

Comment: @maymartin you may want to look at the =Vlookup command from Excel

Comment: @maymartin - if you want to bring in a range go ahead and try this: =ArrayFormula(Reg_Systems!A12:I200)